# How to use Material Design Lite tabs without JavaScript?

Tags: css, material-design

I'm trying to use the [Material Design Lite tabs](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/tabs) but running into some trouble

[image: tabs]

It looks like they are meant to be used where the tab panels are all available on the same page

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
      <a href="#starks-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Starks</a>
      <a href="#lannisters-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Lannisters</a>
      <a href="#targaryens-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Targaryens</a>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="starks-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Eddard</li>
      <li>Catelyn</li>
      <li>Robb</li>
      <li>Sansa</li>
      <li>Brandon</li>
      <li>Arya</li>
      <li>Rickon</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="lannisters-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Tywin</li>
      <li>Cersei</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
      <li>Tyrion</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="targaryens-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Viserys</li>
      <li>Daenerys</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I would like them to look the same as the tabs above, but behave something more like this

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
      <a href="/foo" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Foo</a>
      <a href="/bar" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Bar</a>
      <a href="/other" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Other</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work for me though. When I click the links, the browser will not navigate to the new page.

Any ideas?

Comment: question, do you have a page called `/foo` or a service that understands how to handle that URL?

Comment: @ochi for all intents and purposes, just consider it static html. There's nothing fancy going on.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something in your question.  If static HTML is what you are requesting, your URL is incorrect.  A regular link (`href`) will be requesting the server for a file called `/foo` and, unless you have such file (and the server knows how to respond to such URL) you will not get anything (maybe a 404).  In other words, you would get the default browser behaviour (since you want to avoid using JS to hijack it to do something else like tabbing)

Answer (score 0):

I am obviously missing something in your question but, with my limited understanding of it, here's what I'd do:

You need to create a new HTML file for each tab.  In your case:

- foo.html
- bar.html
- other.html

Your tab panel would look like this for all of them, except the `.is-active` class is placed in different tabs (each page)

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
      <a href="/foo.html" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Foo</a>
      <a href="/bar.html" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Bar</a>
      <a href="/other.html" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Other</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each page also has the content `div` like this with the id matching the page's name.  I.e.

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="foo">
    <ul>
      <li>Eddard</li>
      <li>Catelyn</li>
      <li>Robb</li>
      <li>Sansa</li>
      <li>Brandon</li>
      <li>Arya</li>
      <li>Rickon</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out the ripple effect yet but here is how to get the basic Tab look working with page change:

```
        <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <a href="/foo" class="my-tab is-active">Link 1</a>
        <a href="/bar" class="my-tab">Link 2</a>
    </div>
```

For the CSS Part:

```
.mdl-layout--fixed-tabs .my-tab 
{
    float: none;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-tab 
{
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 24px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mdl-layout.is-upgraded .my-tab.is-active::after 
{
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
}
```